# Lowest salaried employee sql server - not working with MIN function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ended up with a peculiar problem. I am not able to find out the root cause of the issue. Please help.

please create a table by executing below scripts

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_salary (ID INT,emp_name VARCHAR(50),Salary INT)

INSERT INTO Employee_salary VALUES(1,'Dolu',15000)
INSERT INTO Employee_salary VALUES(2,'Bolu',15000)
INSERT INTO Employee_salary VALUES(3,'Kalia',10000)
INSERT INTO Employee_salary VALUES(4,'Bheem',50000)
INSERT INTO Employee_salary VALUES(5,'Krishna',40000)
INSERT INTO Employee_salary VALUES(6,'Chutki',30000)

SELECT * FROM Employee_salary

ID  emp_name    Salary
1   Dolu        15000
2   Bolu        15000
3   Kalia       10000
4   Bheem       50000
5   Krishna     40000
6   Chutki      30000
```

I wanted highest salaried employee, so I found bwlow query

```
SELECT Top 1 emp_name,MAX(salary) from Employee_salary  Group by emp_name
```

I tried to found Lowest salaried employee and tried executing below query by changing 'MAX' to 'MIN'. Surprisingly the below query is not working in any ways. Still it shows 'Bheem, 50000' which is a wrong answer. Can anybody tell me the cause or reason for this issue.

```
SELECT Top 1 emp_name,MIN(salary) from Employee_salary  Group by emp_name
```

Comment: you are getting same record while you face min and max salary with emp_name becuase it will take first record with emp_name group. So Bheem user is single entry in table so min or max salary same for bheem user. does it make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below query from lowest salary:

```
SELECT Top 1 emp_name, salary from Employee_salary order by salary
```

and

```
SELECT Top 1 emp_name, salary from Employee_salary order by salary desc
```

for highest salary.

If there are more than one employee with same salary, try:

```
SELECT Top 1 WITH TIES emp_name, salary from Employee_salary order by salary desc
```

Comment: this will not work. what if there are two persons with lowest salary (say 10000) ? it will retrieve only one.

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho... Thanks for the edit! That's a knowledge for me.!!

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer. I got several other methods to obtain the answer,. But I am curious to know why the below query is not working."SELECT Top 1 emp_name,MIN(salary) from Employee_salary  Group by emp_name"

Comment: Query actually returns the minimum salaries within a group of same employee names. Please check the result by removing the top 1 clause.

Answer (score 1):

tried below query for min and max salary records.

```
-- For Max
SELECT emp_name, salary from Employee_salary where salary = (SELECT Max(salary) from Employee_salary)

-- For Min
SELECT emp_name, salary from Employee_salary where salary = (SELECT Min(salary) from Employee_salary)
```

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer. I got several other methods to obtain the answer,. But I am curious to know why the below query is not working.SELECT Top 1 emp_name,MIN(salary) from Employee_salary  Group by emp_name

Comment: First tried "SELECT emp_name,MIN(salary) from Employee_salary Group by emp_name" this query. See this query return min salary by emp_name grouping. So every user has single value in our case. So min and Max value same for that user

Answer (score 0):

There can be possibilities to multiple rows with same max salary and min salary.
So the below query you can achieve this

```
select s1.emp_name, s1.Salary from Employee_salary as s1 where not exists(select * from Employee_salary as s2 where s2.Salary > s1.Salary);

select s1.emp_name, s1.Salary from Employee_salary as s1 where not exists(select * from Employee_salary as s2 where s2.Salary < s1.Salary);
```

Answer (score -1):

Highest salaried employee

```
SELECT MAX(salary) from Employee_salary
```

This will showing highest salary of employee

If you want to see employee details then

```
SELECT MAX(salary), Employee_salary.* from Employee_salary
```

If you need to lowest salary then you need to add `MIN()` insted of `MAX()`

Comment: Hmm, no... this will not return an `employee` but rather a `salary`

Comment: Ok, if you need employee then add "Employee_salary.*" and add Limit 0,1 at last

Comment: `LIMIT` is MySQL syntax, not MS SQL Server.

Comment: Your second query without a `GROUP BY` is not valid syntax in sql server.