# min() not working in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, min, aggregation

I think I use the correct method(my third attempt) of finding the minimum price I am looking for, but I don't get the answer right. Need some advice!

I have a table named storage, looks like this:

```
    storeNum    productNum    unitPrice 
       1            p1            3.3
       1            p2            4.9
       2            p1            3.6
       3            p1            4.9
       4            p2            4.9
```

I am trying to find the lowest price of each product and the store that has the product.
Here is my first and second attempt:

```
select storeNum, productNum, unitPrice 
from storage, (select min(unitPrice) as minim from storage group by 
productNum) as mint
where carries.uprice=mint.minim

select storeNum, productNum, min(unitPrice)
from storage
group by storeNum, productNum
```

The results are the same:

```
    storeNum    productNum    unitPrice 
       1            p1            3.3
       1            p2            4.9
       3            p1            4.9
       4            p2            4.9
```

p1 should have only one lowest price but it doesn't. So I google it and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486780/lowest-salaried-employee-sql-server-not-working-with-min-function) and have my third attempt:

```
select storeNum, productNum, unitPrice 
from storage
where unitPrice=(select min(unitPrice) from storage group by productNum)
```

The result is a mess:( and I don't know what's wrong with my code.

The result I want is:

```
    storeNum    productNum    unitPrice 
       1            p1            3.3
       1            p2            4.9
       4            p2            4.9
```

Really need some help. Coding is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You have one minimum price per product, so you have to use both product and price to search for stores:

```
SELECT storeNum, productNum, unitPrice
FROM storage
JOIN (SELECT productNum,
             min(unitPrice) AS unitPrice
      FROM storage
      GROUP BY productNum
     ) USING (productNum, unitPrice);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it is not working as the USING part runs some error. No worries, I fixed my code.